# Security implications between doing gpg --export vs copying ~/.gnupg entirely

Tags: backup, gnupg

I'm trying to transfer over my private gpg keys, and I'm running into some weird advice. On one hand, I'm being told to do `gpg --export` and `gpg --export-secret-keys`, and on another, I was recommended to just `cp ~/.gnupg` onto a thumbdrive and plop it onto the new system.

Which would should I be doing? Is there inherently some security implication to do this? Are these system-unique files in .gnupg that should *NOT* be transferred?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`--export` gives you a format that's compatible across all versions (and even other OpenPGP products besides just GnuPG). Copying the directory gives you data that's a little specific to the software version.

For example, if you're switching from a distribution that has the latest GnuPG 2.2.x to one that has a much earlier version or even 2.1.x, it may not be able to read the new data format (the formats of both private-keys-v1 and pubring.kbx are internal to GnuPG and have changed over time). Of course, you can't directly import those files into something like Thunderbird (RNP-based) either, which needs a standard "exported" file.

On the other hand, there is some useful information that doesn't get exported, such as local signatures (`--lsign`) or trust levels, both of which can be exported only if you specify the necessary additional options – as well as non-PGP stuff that GnuPG also handles, such as SSH keys or S/MIME certificates. So if the new system has a similar GnuPG version, it may be preferable to transfer all the files.

In other words, export for future-proof backup, copy for direct transfer between identical systems.

Comment: Valuable information, didnt even consider specifics to a version or OS at all, thanks a lot.